# How to save extra field in has_many_through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two user models: **Advisor** and **Investor**, they are connected with **Relation** model via has_many_through relation. Problem is that i want to save relation between logged in **Investor** user with **Advisor** user found by email. I have the following code:

```
advisor = Advisor.where(:email => params[:invite][:email])
if advisor.exists?
@logged_investor.advisors << advisor
end
```

this works fine, but i need to save an extra field to **Relation** table called "status" which will track a status of their relations. How do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@logged_investor.relations.create(:status => ..., :advisor => ...)
```

Comment: The O.P. is a question I run into about every two months and end up solving the clumsy way , i.e. `Relation.create!(:investor => ..., :advisor => ..., :status => ...)`.  Once in a great while, I remember the more elegant answer given by @victor. ;)

Comment: is there a way to do validation before saving? like new and then valid?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the Relation table just like any other relation by

```
@logged_investor.relations
```

if the modles are setup correctly.
Then just find the relations you want and change the status value.

Its easy to check what kind of methods you can call on an object by using the rails console, like any other command line, pushing tab will give you all the available methods and attributes that object has.